# How to disable grammatical correctness check on input type text fields

Tags: html

Sometime certain words typed into an input type text box, is shown with a red underline on the browser indicating that the word could be grammatically incorrect.

How do I prevent this from showing up?

Comment: You again! Why can't you leave the user's browser alone?

Comment: @deceze - I don't think the words typed into the text box is incorrect. Note: It could be a name and need not be grammatically correct. Is this an invalid scenario?

Comment: But a user can create custom dictionaries that would spellcheck even uncommon words. Especially if it's a name, maybe the user's name, it may be in the custom dictionary. This is a nonstandard feature on browsers anyway, users that have spellchecking enabled usually **want** it.

Comment: @deceze - I just don't want it to be shown on the loginid field alone.

Comment: There are certainly legitimate reasons to want to disable spellchecking. For example, it doesn't make sense to spellcheck a randomly generated CAPTCHA, a GUID, or a product serial number.

Comment: @Gabe But people *are used* to getting red squiggles in these cases. I'd expect my spellchecker to be broken if that suddenly stopped working, which would cast doubt on the reliability of my spellchecker. How would I know the difference between there being no read line because I spelled everything correctly, or because the website author decided to disable my spellchecker? Inconsistency is bad.

Comment: deceze: Seriously? You actually notice when there's no red underline on a CAPTCHA?

Comment: @Gabe I'm a spellchecker fanatic. >:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the spellcheck attribute to the input type text field and it disabled spell checks just for that field. The above fix works, thanks for all who responded.

Comment: I do not believe this person taking the time to return with a valid solution to their problem deserved that down-vote. I think there are situations where removing spell-check highlighting lends to a better UI, which is why the attribute exists in the first place. Input searching / auto-completing usernames for example where the red underline would get in the way aesthetically and is not useful.

Answer (score 47):

In case someone stumbles across this like I did and doesn't know what attribute to use, you can disable spellcheck for a specific input field or text area using the spellcheck attribute:

```
<input type="text" spellcheck="false"/>
```

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Controlling_spell_checking_in_HTML_forms)

Answer (score 8):

You can use:

```
<input type="text" spellcheck="false">
```

Add the "spellcheck" attribute to the `<input>` tag and set it to `false`.